# Turning of modules in XCode hides errors

Tags: c, xcode

I am writing a program in c and I have noticed that when i set the setting *Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)* to No in XCode all errors i get while writing my code disappear.

For example if i were to randomly write a bunch a characters in the middle of my program XCode wouldn't put tell me anythings wrong until i compiled the program.

When the setting is off:

[image: Image were there are no red squiggly lines]

When the setting is on:

[image: Image were there are red squiggly lines]

This is really annoying for obvious reasons and it **ONLY** happens when I turn of the setting, if I turn it back on the errors appear again.

I need to have modules disabled for the program i'm writing. How can I fix this and why would turning off modules disable errors?

Comment: What do you mean by enable and disable "errors"? Do you mean something like the red "squigly" lines that are common in code-oriented editors to show the editors analysis of the code?  If it's about graphical elements in the editor itself, please create screenshots of both "enabled" and "disabled", and [edit] your question to show them.

Comment: Yes i mean red squiggly lines, I have edited my question to include some images.